# How to remove commas from a certain field in CSV?

Tags: text-processing, csv

There is a field/column in a CSV file Im working with called name, this is always the second field.

The values in this column are like: "Smith, John" "Brady, Tom" "Manning, Peyton" etc

How do I make it without a comma (like "Smith John" or "Brady Tom") and leave everything as is? I have tried using sed awk but cant figure it out.

Comment: [edit] your question to contain concise, testable sample input and expected output (a multi-field, multi-line CSV, not just an example of 1 field from a CSV) so we can best help you.

Comment: Your sample data isn't clear: have you used double quotes to stand out the fields in your sentence, or are the double quotes part of the fields? (If it's proper CSV then at least the field containing a comma will be double-quoted.) Use the code marker `{}` to highlight the actual data in your data file

Answer (score 6):

If the field is quoted correctly, like you show, then the embedded commas shouldn't be an issue, assuming you read the data with a CSV-aware parser.

If you still believe you need to remove the commas in the field named `name`, then use a CSV-aware parser like [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to process the data.

Here's an example using Miller:

```bash
mlr --csv put '$name = gsub($name, ",", "")' file.csv
```

This reads the data from `file.csv` as CSV, uses a substitution function not unlike what you would find in `awk` to remove all commas from the field named `name`, and then outputs the possibly modified records.

Example:

```bash
$ cat file.csv
age,name,note
47,"Hatter, Mad","Isn't actually ""mad"""
39,"Rabbit, White",Drinks too much tea
2,"Dormouse, The",Sleeps most of the time
$ mlr --csv put '$name = gsub($name, ",", "")' file.csv
age,name,note
47,Hatter Mad,"Isn't actually ""mad"""
39,Rabbit White,Drinks too much tea
2,Dormouse The,Sleeps most of the time
```

With `csvformat` (from csvkit) and `tr`, the following would remove all commas by temporarily changing the delimiter of the document to semi-colon:

```bash
csvformat -D ';' file.csv | tr -d , | csvformat -d ';'
```

Example:

```bash
$ csvformat -D ';' file.csv | tr -d , | csvformat -d ';'
age,name,note
47,Hatter Mad,"Isn't actually ""mad"""
39,Rabbit White,Drinks too much tea
2,Dormouse The,Sleeps most of the time
```

Or, you could use `csvsql` (also from csvkit) to remove the commas from only the `name` field with a bit of SQL:

```bash
csvsql --query 'UPDATE file SET name = REPLACE(name, ",", "")' \
    --query 'SELECT * FROM file' file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a CSV as provided in [@Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/746405/133219):

```
$ cat file.csv
age,name,note
47,"Hatter, Mad","Isn't actually ""mad"""
39,"Rabbit, White",Drinks too much tea
2,"Dormouse, The",Sleeps most of the time
```

we have the concise but fragile (would break if the first field was also quoted or the 2nd field contained escaped quotes) way using any awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {sub(/,/,"",$2)} 1' file.csv
age,name,note
47,"Hatter Mad","Isn't actually ""mad"""
39,"Rabbit White",Drinks too much tea
2,"Dormouse The",Sleeps most of the time
```

and the less concise but robust (will work for any field contents except newlines, assuming quotes inside fields are escaped by doubling them per [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)) way using GNU awk for `FPAT`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"([^\"]|\"\")*\")"; OFS=","} {sub(/,/,"",$2)} 1' file.csv
age,name,note
47,"Hatter Mad","Isn't actually ""mad"""
39,"Rabbit White",Drinks too much tea
2,"Dormouse The",Sleeps most of the time
```

Which one you need to use depends on the contents of the CSV.

If your quoted fields can contain newlines, or you have a CSV that the first script above won't work for and you can't get GNU awk, then you need a different solution, e.g. see [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk)

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing  @Kusalananda's CSV example, you can use a Ruby with the default CSV parser:

```
$ ruby -r csv -e 'data=CSV.parse($<.read, **{:headers=>true})
data["name"]=data["name"].map{|e| e.gsub(/,/,"")}
puts data' file.csv
age,name,note
47,Hatter Mad,"Isn't actually ""mad"""
39,Rabbit White,Drinks too much tea
2,Dormouse The,Sleeps most of the time
```

Or if you want to reverse the names so they are more proper without the comma:

```
$ ruby -r csv -e 'data=CSV.parse($<.read, **{:headers=>true})
data["name"]=data["name"].map{|e| e.split(/,\s*/,2).reverse.join(" ")}
puts data' file.csv
age,name,note
47,Mad Hatter,"Isn't actually ""mad"""
39,White Rabbit,Drinks too much tea
2,The Dormouse,Sleeps most of the time
```

Answer (score 0):

CSV is complicated and it won't be fun to reimplement the syntax in sed/awk.

Assuming you're working with a valid CSV (the commas are properly escaped and/or quoted) then you can use something like https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/. For example you can use `csvsql` to run a SQL-style query to strip the commas from that field.

Most programming languages have CSV libraries so you can write say a short Python script to do it also.

You can also just open the file in something like LibreOffice Calc and do it by hand.

I'd give examples but you haven't provided sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*Parse CSV with Raku's `Text::CSV` module:*

```perl
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'my @a = csv(in => $*IN, strict => True);  \
         @a.skip>>.[1] = @a.skip>>.[1].map: *.trans( "," => "");  \
         .join("\t").put for @a;'  <  file.csv
```

Sample Input (from @Kusalananda):

```
age,name,note
47,"Hatter, Mad","Isn't actually ""mad"""
39,"Rabbit, White",Drinks too much tea
2,"Dormouse, The",Sleeps most of the time
```

*Below shows tab-spaced column output for readability, as directed by the code above (to generate CSV file use `join(",")` instead).*

Sample Output (1)

```
age name    note
47  Hatter Mad  Isn't actually "mad"
39  Rabbit White    Drinks too much tea
2   Dormouse The    Sleeps most of the time
```

If you have issues with stray whitespace within columns, you can use `.trim`, etc. Also, the OP might also want to reverse the contents of column 2 to read firstname then lastname. If so, then `split`ting that field on comma might be best. Note you can change the final statement from above to `csv(in => @a, out => $*OUT, sep_char => "\t")`, which generates an authentic TSV (or CSV) file:

```perl
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'my @a = csv(in => "Mad_Hatter.csv", strict => True);  \
         @a.skip>>.[1] = @a.skip>>.[1].map: *.split(", ").reverse;  \
         csv(in => @a, out => $*OUT, sep_char => "\t");'  < file.csv
```

Sample Output (2)

```
age name    note
47  "Mad Hatter"    "Isn't actually ""mad"""
39  "White Rabbit"  "Drinks too much tea"
2   "The Dormouse"  "Sleeps most of the time"
```

https://modules.raku.org/dist/Text::CSV:cpan:HMBRAND
https://github.com/Tux/CSV
https://raku.org